# MVC3 app ignoring Razor .cshtml extension

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to run an MVC3 with Razor web project for the first time. The project was generated by S#arp Architecture, so there could be some wiring missing.

The de facto web.config with the Razor entries has been created under the Views folder. Here is the error for ~/

```
[InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Index.aspx
~/Index.ascx
~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx]
```

Any idea what's missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
```

To

```
Application_Start()
```

in Global.asax.cs

Did the trick

Comment: Why is this required? I don't see this line in default MVC3 projects. Thanks.

Comment: View engines are pluggable. I can only guess that the mvc 3 architects assumed we wouldn't be wanting razor by default!?